# Sorry to hear that

Tags: conversation

How should I reply when someone says:

> Sorry to hear that

The situation may be

- Feeling sick
- Someone close to you deceased
- Talking about an accident
- Talking about someone's sittuation
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reply is not required.  The person is showing empathy for your plight.  You could thank them for their sympathy or simply move to a different subject.